# Adding an image inside cell based on cell value

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a faux progressive checkbox that cycles through 3 states. The default checkbox in Google Sheets seems to only have two states, true or false. I am trying to either edit this to have a third state, and then change the image in the checkbox based on the state, or create my own fake checkbox that adds an appropriate image based on a number in the box (e.g. 1,2 or 3.)

I am basically a novice with Google Sheets, but I've seen a similar function in other sheets.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/120011/186471

Answer (score 0):

Your issue can be solved by making use of Apps Script and triggers.

You can use an `onEdit` trigger like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 1 && e.range.getRow() == 1) {
    if (e.value == '1')
      // insert the image corresponding to '1'
    else if (e.value == '2')
      // insert the image corresponding to '2'
    else if (e.value == '3')
      // insert the image corresponding to '3'
  }
}
```

The `onEdit` trigger works by detecting where the edit in the Spreadsheet has been done and based on this it executes the instructions needed.

For example, in the script above the "checkbox" will be in the cell `A1` (row 1, column 1).

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events);
- [Apps Script onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite).